# Firebase Authentication SDKs for 3.xx

Tags: firebase, angularfire, firebase-authentication

Whenever I try to create a new user in Firebase 3.xx, I'm getting error response as`Projects created at console.firebase.google.com must use the new Firebase Authentication SDKs available from firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ .`
Not sure which code to change to use firebase 3.xx authentication sdk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the steps to switch to Firebase v3:

1) Install Firebase v3 in your web project following these simple instructions:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#prerequisites
In this link they show a code snippet you need to include. You can find it personalized for your project in your project's console>"Add firebase to your web app"

[image]
NOTE: Now you probably have 2 Firebase SDKs installed in your project. I don't think this is good so I suggest to update your code to use the Firebase v3 and then remove the older Firebase SDK import, that should look like this

```
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.4/firebase.js"></script>
```

2) Update your Angularfire version. Here's how to do it: [ù](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire)

3) Update your code to use Firebase v3. For example 
To detect the auth state with the older Firebase you use:

```
authObj.$onAuth(function(authData) {})
```

To detect the auth state with the older Firebase you have to use:

```
$firebaseAuth.$onAuthStateChanged(callback[, context])
```

Hope it helps ;)

Comment: Did upgrade from firebase 2.xx to 3.xx, but now it says "onAuthStateChanged is not a function". Haven't I upgraded to 3.xx successfully yet? I am guessing authenticating a user is lot different in 3.xx then was in 2.xx firebase. Can you please help me with authentication?

Comment: The auth process is the same but you use different functions. e.g. onAuth in v3 is onAuthStateChanged.
Sure I can :) Just one question, are you using AngularFire?

Comment: Yes I'm using AngularFire 2.0

Comment: Please answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38013419/on-auth-state-changed-angularfire