# On Auth State changed AngularFire

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire, firebase-authentication

Trying to authenticate an user using firebase. Started my app using firebase 2.xx but even after upgrading to Firebase 3.xx, throwing
error "onAuthStateChanged is not a function".

This is how my login function looks like-

```
.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope','$location','CommonProp','$firebaseAuth', '$firebaseObject',function($scope,$location,CommonProp,$firebaseAuth,$firebaseObject) {

    var firebaseObj = $firebaseObject(rootRef);
    var loginObj = $firebaseAuth(firebaseObj); 

    $scope.SignIn = function($scope, user) {
    event.preventDefault(); // To prevent form refresh
    var username = user.email;
    var password = user.password;


    loginObj.$signInWithEmailAndPassword({
            email: username,
            password: password
        })
        .then(function(user) {
            // Success callback
            console.log('Authentication successful');
            $location.path("/welcome");
            CommonProp.setUser(user.password.email);
        }, function(error) {
            // Failure callback
            console.log(error);
        });
}
}]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are passing a `$firebaseObject` to `$firebaseAuth()`.

So make sure you are initializing your `[$firebaseAuth][1]` object like the following and then your code should work properly.

```
var loginObj = $firebaseAuth();
```

Working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9bz4Lwxa/70/) for demonstrating.

You can check here the documentation for [AngularFire2](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/reference.md)